# Best practice concerning private arraylist and other such constructions

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, class-design

I have the following class which I'm fighting over how to implement. The question is whether or not it makes sense to have a private collection item, in this case an arraylist, a a member. I am well aware it is considered best practice to have getters and setters for any class members, but in this case having a getter and setter would require re-implementing (or rather duplicating) large amounts of the ArrayList functionality.

Example class:

```
public class Email
{
    private ArrayList<String> To;
    private ArrayList<String> Cc;
    private ArrayList<String> Bcc;

    ...
}
```

I assume the answer is I should indeed implement getters and setters for these arrays? Is there some approach I haven't thought of regarding handling this type of situation? The easy solution to managing these lists is to set the private modifiers to public and check the array data is valid on calling methods, but is this right? Can anyone point me in the direction of other SO questions, design patterns etc I should consider?

Comment: No brackets on the class name - compile error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually in that case I think it would be better to not provide a direct getter/setter combination.

I would rather approach it the following way:

1. Change the type to `List<String>` (best practice to use Interfaces on fields.)
2. Initialize an empty `ArrayList`s in the constructor.
3. Provide delegates for `add`, `remove`, `hasTo/Cc/Bcc`.

In that way you could decorate each collection with additional functionality, e.g. making sure the String contains a valid recipient information.

```
public void addTo(String recipient){
  // validate recipient
  this.to.add(recipient);
}

public String removeTo(String recipient){
  return this.to.remove(recipient);
}

public boolean hasTo(){
  return this.to.size() > 0;
}
```

*EDIT*

I forgot to mention that a getter makes sense since you need that when processing the Email. But look at [the other answer on considering to returning an unmodifiable `List`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543771/best-practice-concerning-private-arraylist-and-other-such-constructions/3543785#3543785).

Comment: @fish: let's not fight that holy war here :)

Comment: I'd have probably used `this`... sorry! Anyway, ok, thank you, I was hoping to avoid having to write delegate functions to hide the list features. It does look like the best way forward though. Thanks.

Comment: Further to this answer, I would consider the ideal API of the calling code.  Perhaps there is never any need to call removeTo() and you might find it makes sense to have a setter like: setTo( final String.. addresses )

Answer (score 6):

> I am well aware it is considered best
>   practice to have getters and setters
>   for any class members.

I disagree.  Only expose what you need to!  Try to think in terms of ADTs (abstract Data Types).  In other words, create a layer of abstraction from the internal `ArrayLists`.  Anyone using your class should not know you are internally using `ArrayLists`.  Unless absolutely necessary, you should not provide a getter for your `ArrayLists`.  If you feel like you need these, think about returning a `List` and using [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) to prevent modification through a getter.

Comment: +1 for the idea about using `unmodifiableList` in the getter to ensure the usage of of provided methods to manipulate the list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of using unmodifiablelist, I hadn't thought of that. I didn't want to use a getter/setter pair for the list itself (might as well declare it public) but wanted to avoid the case of continually writing .add .remove .has etc.

Answer (score 2):

> I am well aware it is considered best practice to have getters and setters for any class members.

That is incorrect.

The relevant "best practice" advice is NOT to expose a classes state as fields.

If you do need to make the state visible, getters and setters are one option, but *not necessarily* the most appropriate option.  In deciding which of the various options is best, you need to consider questions like:

- Is the state that I'm exposing an internal implementation detail of the ADT, or a reference to a separate data entity?
- If I expose an internal implementation detail, how do I prevent something depending on it, or (worse still) changing it in potentially disruptive ways?

Well implemented getters and setters can address these concerns; e.g. by returning copies of collections, or unmodifiable wrappers, and/or by copying collection arguments.  But wrapper methods can do the same, often with less runtime overheads.

The other thing to consider is whether there are performance imperatives that make it necessary to eschew "best practice" design principles and deliberately make the ADT "leaky".